# mailing in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working on android platform. I want to send some data to a email address in android platform. Is there any class which can provide me facilities to send data . If there is a process to send data to any email address in android???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how you send an HTML email to someone:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"mame@example.com", "name2@example.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("my html text goes here"));
startActivity(intent);
```

to send an email with a PNG attachment, where `pngDirectory` is a `File` pointing to the images' location, and `pngFileName` is the file name of the file(`myFile.png`):

```
String pngLocation = "file://" + pngDirectory.getPath() + "/" + pngFileName;
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            .setType("image/png")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(pngLocation))
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "blah")
        );
```